# Display a panel after a radio button is selected

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm native at Angular. I have created a panel which contains two radio buttons(`Compaign` and `Script`) and an `ok` button in the panel footer. I would like to display `compaign` panel (1st radio button) while clicking on `Compaign` choice and `ok` for confirmation. On the other hand, I  would like to display `Script` panel while clicking on `Script` option (2nd radio button) and `ok` for confirmation. But I'm having some trouble with my code.

**gotosearch.html**

```html
<form [(formGroup)]="choosewindowForm">
    <!-- difinition simple de FormGroup-->
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Select an option to start the search </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">

            <!--Compaign button-->
            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <!-- radio inline to inline both buttons in the same line-->
                    <input type="radio" value="compaign" name="option" [(ngModel)]="option">
                    <!--mutually execlusive-->
                    Compaign
                </label>

            </div>

            <!--  Script button-->
            <div class="form-control">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" value="script" name="option" [(ngModel)]="option">
                    <!--To make the two buttons mutually execlusive we have to add (name="option") in both buttons -->
                    Script
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- OK button  -->
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">ok</button>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Intorduction to the tow panels-->

    <!-- 1st panel of Compaign-->
    <form class="example-form">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Search using Compaign parameters</h3>
            </div>

            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <textarea matInput placeholder="Request ID"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div class="panel-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Start !</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <!-- 2nd panel for script-->
    <form class="example-form">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Search using Script parameters</h3>
            </div>

            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <textarea matInput placeholder="Request ID"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <textarea matInput placeholder="ICCID"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <textarea matInput placeholder="Send DATE"></textarea>
            </mat-form-field>

            <div class="panel-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Start !</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</form>
```

**gotosearch.ts**

```js
export class GotosearchComponent implements OnInit {
    choosewindowForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.choosewindowForm = new FormGroup({

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `formGroup` doesn't do anything here. To use reactive forms, see the examples in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Here since you have used `ngModel` on the radio buttons, you can use it along with [`ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) to conditionally display the `Compaign` or `Script` panels.

```html
<!-- 1st panel of Compaign-->
<form class="example-form" *ngIf="option === 'compaign'">
    <!-- Compaign panel content goes here -->
</form>

<!-- 2nd panel for script-->
<form class="example-form" *ngIf="option === 'script'">
    <!-- Script panel content goes here -->
</form>
```

where `compaign` and `script` are the values of your radio buttons respectively.

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-ng-if).

Comment: However Man ! When im runinng the console !! the two panels are both disappearing ! Even If i clicked on either ( Compain or Script ) button !!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. What do you mean by running the console? This shouldn't be an issue with `ngIf` though. The `ngIf` will work as long as the condition is `true`.

Comment: Im meant ! when i type npm start to run my project !! It displays the panel of choices (either script or compaign buttons) !! However ,when i click of one of them it doesnt display anything !!

Comment: You must have changed something else especially since you said it was working initially. I have added a working example in my answer. Are you seeing any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No ! it doesnt work initially !! Like you mentioned previously ! there is an error concerning the use of FormGroup declaring that (ngModel cannot be used to register form controls with a parent formGroup directive).But I dont think, it affects the display of the panels. Well , the StackBlitz project doesnt add anything new ! becauz i have perhaps do the same stuffs ! However,you have to add an Ok button below the two choices , and when you  make the choice ,and you follow it by the" "Ok"  to confirm , it displays the appropriate panel;So i think we should add a method to embedd the ok button

Comment: That is exactly the issue, you cannot use `formGroup` and `ngModel` together. Use one or the other. In my example, I did not use `formGroup`. Check out my example, in the template uncomment the `form` element which contains `formGroup` and you'll see that the panels don't show anymore. Either get rid of `formGroup` or if you really need it, then you'll need to replace `ngModel` with `formControl`.

Comment: I fixed all stuffs (ngModel to formControlName) ! However , when i run my project it displays this error (Cannot find control with name: 'option') !! Its very werid !...I typed those following lines in my template ( while transformtion )<input type="radio" value="Script" formControlName="option" name="option">#For Script ..And for #Compaing I wrote this <input type="radio" value="name" formControlName="option" name="option"> !! And to be sure that all stuffs should work correctly ..! I add this code line in my ts iniside ngOnit(){  compaign: new FormControl() } ..! unfortunately it doesnt work

Comment: That's not weird at all. Your answer is basically in your question. Your error says it cannot find `option`, your formControl name should be `option` and not `compaign` in `ngOnInit`. There are many examples in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). Please read them. If you still have problems, I suggest you create a new question since it's not associated with the OP.